# Combining columns as string after groupby aggregation in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this that comes after some statistic model experimentation.

```
    data = {
        "cat1": {
            (1, "class1", "metric1"): 0.9520103335380554,
            (1, "class1", "metric2"): 0.9596380591392517,
            (1, "class2", "metric1"): 0.9013115167617798,
            (1, "class2", "metric2"): 0.9917504191398621,
            (1, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9027230143547058,
            (1, "class3", "metric2"): 0.8536863327026367,
            (2, "class1", "metric1"): 0.8746241331100464,
            (2, "class1", "metric2"): 0.8844705820083618,
            (2, "class2", "metric1"): 0.7890198826789856,
            (2, "class2", "metric2"): 0.6964980363845825,
            (2, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9410034418106079,
            (2, "class3", "metric2"): 0.9601017236709595,
            (3, "class1", "metric1"): 0.9640659689903259,
            (3, "class1", "metric2"): 0.9766426682472229,
            (3, "class2", "metric1"): 0.893884003162384,
            (3, "class2", "metric2"): 0.9959416389465332,
            (3, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9533607363700867,
            (3, "class3", "metric2"): 0.9378591179847717,
        },
        "cat2": {
            (1, "class1", "metric1"): 0.9520103335380554,
            (1, "class1", "metric2"): 0.9596380591392517,
            (1, "class2", "metric1"): 0.9013115167617798,
            (1, "class2", "metric2"): 0.9917504191398621,
            (1, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9027230143547058,
            (1, "class3", "metric2"): 0.8536863327026367,
            (2, "class1", "metric1"): 0.8746241331100464,
            (2, "class1", "metric2"): 0.8844705820083618,
            (2, "class2", "metric1"): 0.7890198826789856,
            (2, "class2", "metric2"): 0.6964980363845825,
            (2, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9410034418106079,
            (2, "class3", "metric2"): 0.9601017236709595,
            (3, "class1", "metric1"): 0.9640659689903259,
            (3, "class1", "metric2"): 0.9766426682472229,
            (3, "class2", "metric1"): 0.893884003162384,
            (3, "class2", "metric2"): 0.9959416389465332,
            (3, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9533607363700867,
            (3, "class3", "metric2"): 0.9378591179847717,
        },
        "cat3": {
            (1, "class1", "metric1"): 0.8746241331100464,
            (1, "class1", "metric2"): 0.8844705820083618,
            (1, "class2", "metric1"): 0.7890198826789856,
            (1, "class2", "metric2"): 0.6964980363845825,
            (1, "class3", "metric1"): 0.9410034418106079,
            (1, "class3", "metric2"): 0.9601017236709595,
            (2, "class1", "metric1"): 0.9309893846511841,
            (2, "class1", "metric2"): 0.884644627571106,
            (2, "class2", "metric1"): 0.861851155757904,
            (2, "class2", "metric2"): 0.9180170893669128,
            (2, "class3", "metric1"): 0.8841384649276733,
            (2, "class3", "metric2"): 0.8577012419700623,
            (3, "class1", "metric1"): 0.8895564675331116,
            (3, "class1", "metric2"): 0.8351058959960938,
            (3, "class2", "metric1"): 0.832390308380127,
            (3, "class2", "metric2"): 0.8969333171844482,
            (3, "class3", "metric1"): 0.7883192300796509,
            (3, "class3", "metric2"): 0.8577012419700623,
        },
    }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df = df.rename_axis(("experiment", "class", "metric"))
    df.groupby(["class", "metric"]).agg(["mean", "std"])
```

[image]

After grouping and aggregating for each experiment, how do I merge the columns of the second level of the multi index, so the output the string concatenation and rounding inserting some symbol in between, something like this:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change function with `f-string` for custom ouput:

```
f = lambda x: f'{round(x.mean(), 2)} +/- {round(x.std(), 2)}'
df = df.groupby(["class", "metric"]).agg(f)
print (df)
                         cat1           cat2           cat3
class  metric                                              
class1 metric1  0.93 +/- 0.05  0.93 +/- 0.05   0.9 +/- 0.03
       metric2  0.94 +/- 0.05  0.94 +/- 0.05  0.87 +/- 0.03
class2 metric1  0.86 +/- 0.06  0.86 +/- 0.06  0.83 +/- 0.04
       metric2  0.89 +/- 0.17  0.89 +/- 0.17  0.84 +/- 0.12
class3 metric1  0.93 +/- 0.03  0.93 +/- 0.03  0.87 +/- 0.08
       metric2  0.92 +/- 0.06  0.92 +/- 0.06  0.89 +/- 0.06
```

Or select levels by [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html), round with convert to string and last join by `+/-`:

```
df = df.groupby(["class", "metric"]).agg(["mean", "std"])

df = (df.xs('mean', axis=1, level=1).round(2).astype(str) + '+/-' + 
      df.xs('std', axis=1, level=1).round(2).astype(str))
print (df)
                       cat1         cat2         cat3
class  metric                                        
class1 metric1  0.93+/-0.05  0.93+/-0.05   0.9+/-0.03
       metric2  0.94+/-0.05  0.94+/-0.05  0.87+/-0.03
class2 metric1  0.86+/-0.06  0.86+/-0.06  0.83+/-0.04
       metric2  0.89+/-0.17  0.89+/-0.17  0.84+/-0.12
class3 metric1  0.93+/-0.03  0.93+/-0.03  0.87+/-0.08
       metric2  0.92+/-0.06  0.92+/-0.06  0.89+/-0.06
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `stack`+`apply`+`unstack`:

```
(df.groupby(["class", "metric"])
   .agg(["mean", "std"])
   .stack(level=0)
   .apply(lambda r: f'{r["mean"]:.2f}±{r["std"]:.2f}', axis=1)
   .unstack(level=-1)
)
```

output:

```
                     cat1       cat2       cat3
class  metric                                  
class1 metric1  0.93±0.05  0.93±0.05  0.90±0.03
       metric2  0.94±0.05  0.94±0.05  0.87±0.03
class2 metric1  0.86±0.06  0.86±0.06  0.83±0.04
       metric2  0.89±0.17  0.89±0.17  0.84±0.12
class3 metric1  0.93±0.03  0.93±0.03  0.87±0.08
       metric2  0.92±0.06  0.92±0.06  0.89±0.06
```